# Linker errors after commenting out a couple of functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, linker

I need some ideas here. 
The code is divided into multiple projects, and the error happens on the main project statically linking a sub-project.
I have probably messed up something in the setings of the subproject, but I can't figure out how to solve this exactly.

But basically I've now found two functions from the subproject which if I use in the main project, everything compiles fine. If I comment out those function calls from the source of the main project, it gives me linker errors on some of the functions that were not commented out. (from the same subproject.)

When everything compiles fine, I get a couple of linker warnings "warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol", maybe that has something to do with it?

How does one approach fixing such a problem? Any suggestions are welcome.

(Tried: building/rebuilding everything).

Comment: I think you're going to need to show the linker command line and probably the symbol table contents for the (non-system) libraries and object files on it.  The MSDN page for that error seems pretty clear to me, what part of what you're seeing isn't answered there?

Comment: I'll check into that but you did read and understood that the mentioned linker warning is not my problem right? I just thought it might have something to do with the actual problem. I am yet to read the whole msdn page on that but it surely can't state that the linker is supposed to break when I remove function calls (which is the real problem), can it?

Comment: No, I'm sorry to say I saw what I expected to see, not what was there.   Very old-school linkers scan the library and object files given serially, once, so if nothing in a library seems necessary when the linker encounters it, it won't be included and the linker will not remember seeing it, so later inputs referencing anything there will stay unresolved ... unless you include it again ...

Comment: Well thanks anyway, I'll try to fix the warning first, maybe the problem will evaporate.

Answer (score 0):

You have most likely messed up opening and closing (curly) brackets.

You either commented out one too many or left one uncommented.